# Open editor post in a popup

Tags: urls, editor

I use this code to open the popup editor.

```
<script>
    function edit() {
       var pop = window.open(' <?php echo get_edit_post_link(); ?> ', '_blank', 'screenX=200,screenY=200,width=1000,height=600');
        }
    </script>
<a href="" onclick="edit()" >Edit</a>
```

This returns this url: `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=122&amp;action=edit`

But it shows: `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php`

The problems is this "%amp;"

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `get_edit_post_link` to not use the ampersands as specified [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_edit_post_link). Try this instead:

```
   var pop = window.open(' <?php echo get_edit_post_link(get_the_ID(), ''); ?> ', '_blank', 'screenX=200,screenY=200,width=1000,height=600');
```